# command-line downgrading catalina to mojave

Tags: time-machine, command-line, catalina, downgrade

After a plenty of issues I would like to know if somebody has a "recipe" to perform a manual downgrade to mojave 10.14.

I installed catalina after waiting for 10.15.1 and at the beginning seemed to perform well, so I've updated time machine backups, losing the possibility of go back in an usual mode.

I've read how to get rid of catalina by wipping the main internal drive, but I'ld like to know if somebody has been able to properly copy back files/directories (say /Applications, /Library, user library /usr/local/ etc) from the catalina Time Machine backup and get them work back in mojave without reinstalling everything. I feel confident with bash shell, so that's not a problem, I just would like to know if its possible to get things working in that way.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting challenge. I doubt this is feasible though, both in general (because you are replacing binaries and libraries the currently running system still needs) and specifically (due to the split between system and non-system partition Catalina introduced)

Comment: *"... so I've updated time machine backups..."*: Do you have a few Time Machine snapshots only?

Comment: It's not reasonably possible.  Nuke the drive, reinstall Mojave, restore your backup.

Comment: @klanomath I've 2 disks with Time Machine copies and another custom system (duplicity, from my linux times) for automated daily copies. The problem with time machine is that catalina deleted mojave all snapshots

Comment: @MarcWilson What you say is what I'll do, but in the last step "restore backup" I intend to restore the most I can

Comment: @avelo In contrary to Marc I wouldn't **restore** (e.g. with Migration Assistant or TM) anything from the backup. A lot of content in /Lib, ~/Lib etc. probably contains "upgraded" library and support files. E.g. I doubt that you can use the ~/Library/Mail (Catalina) or the whole Music/Podcast/ etc libs in Mojave. Mojave's iTunes had a unified lib which doesn't exist in Catalina anymore since all is split there. You're left with copying all fitting data with the Finder.

Comment: @nohillside I'm not telling about directly go back to mojave without reinstalling. I know about the new partition system, so I'll probably proceed by installing mojave in an external disk, start in recovery to move all applications and data from main to external, boot from external, check, and finally wipe main drive and clone the external to the internal. I suppose that binaries would not be a problem, as when updating to catalina, all these apps (/applications, homebrew, conda...) where moved by the installer, my doubts came from some apple contens of /library and users library

Comment: @klanomath I'm not using apple mail app but thunderbird, nor music or itunes. I came from linux so i'm almost no using apple apps appart from basic system ones.

Comment: @avelo Even brew often uses system specific installer packages.

Comment: Well, you'll know whether if works once you've done it. But I doubt that there can be any specific answer for your specific setup.

Comment: @klanomath yes, but were migrated to catalina directly without any issue. Anyway, I could survive to brew and conda reinstalling, the pain are the /applications and settings

Comment: @nohillside I know, but I was just looking for anybody who did that for the basic system move, I could then deal with my setup

Comment: I fail to see the benefit here, compared to just reinstalling Mojave while keeping /Applications and /Users untouched (or backing them up first and restoring afterwards). But I miss some parts of the issue here, so it‘s probably better to wish you good luck with this (and invite you to post an answer below afterwards).

Comment: @avelo People shouldn't have to be told to not restore a Catalina backup on top of Mojave.  But I should have explicitly stated restore your prior backup, I suppose.  If you don't have one, I'd just backup your data, then re-install.

Comment: @MarcWilson Didn't proper understand, I've not pre-catalina backup (time machine deleted them, even when I had enough room), but you mean that a catalina backup works to restore over mojave? If that is the case I'll do that. My fault then for not thinking in the easiest way.

Comment: @avelo Actually I said the exact reverse of that.